# Can you use a shortcut key or python to open a specified N panel in the sidebar?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if it's possible to "go to" a named panel on the N sidebar-- either by shortcut key or python.

For instance, say I have an addon called "my cool addon" and it's a tab in the N sidebar. I would like users to be able to press a key combination and have the sidebar open (if it's closed) and then select the "my cool addon" tab.

Comment: Could you please add a hypothetical example to clarify "go to"?

Comment: @batFINGER he's looking for the ability to open a particular add-on's tab in the side bar.  For instance, if you have HardOps or Rigify installed and enabled, they'll both have tabs in the sidebar, so a method like using Shift-Fn to switch the editor window but to focus on, say, the Rigify tab.

Comment: A workaround is showing addon panels as   a popover.. (_eg_ viewport overlays is a panel popover.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "go to" means set the focus of the sidebar to that specific tab, then as far as I know, no.  You can usually tell if such a thing is possible in Python by enabling the the Python tool tips and hovering over the tool/input/window/etc.  In the case of the layout tab it will tell you **window.workspace** which will lead you to the method, for example.

It's odd, because you can scroll the tabs by hovering and using the scroll wheel.  Time for a feature request?

Comment: Yes, I would like that feature request-- and while we're add it, please allow developers to use icons instead of names for those tabs as well!