# Activate specific N-Panel Tab via hotkey

Tags: keymap

Is it possible to select a specific N-Panel tab via hotkey like you can with workspaces using the `wm.context_set_id` and `window.workspaces` command in the keymap?

Comment: By default, no.  Blender doesn't have support for moving between regions within an area and definitely doesn't support moving between tabs within a region like the sidepanel ("n panel") or the properties editor.

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/237218/42221) answer your question?